# How to make functionality to be available for iOS greater than 8 with AppDelegate upgrade

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, appdelegate

I upgraded my AppDelegate from this

```
// MARK: - Core Data stack

    lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: URL = {
        let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        return urls[urls.count-1]
    }()

    lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
        let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "TestProject", withExtension: "momd")!
        return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL)!
    }()

    lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {

        // Create the coordinator and store
        let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
        let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")
        var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
        do {
            try coordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: url, options: nil)
        } catch {
            // Report any error we got.
            var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
            dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data" as AnyObject?
            dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason as AnyObject?

            dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError
            let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)

            NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }

        return coordinator
    }()

    lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
        let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
        var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
        return managedObjectContext
    }()

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    func saveContext () {
        if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
            do {
                try managedObjectContext.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nserror = error as NSError
                NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                abort()
            }
        }
    }
```

to this so that I can use iOS 10 for coding core data  with Swift 3

```
// MARK: - Core Data stack

    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "TestProject")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {

                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
```

But when I am coding in view controller, I am getting these available for iOS 10.0

```
@IBAction func saveBtnPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let context =   (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

            let task = Task(context: context)
            task.taskDesc = goalText.text!
            task.taskImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(choosenImage!)! as NSData?

        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
        //Save the data to coredata
        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
    }
```

Is there anyway, I can use iOS 10 with swift 3 syntax and make functionality available for all devices which uses iOS 8 and more. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can ship Swift 3 code against iOSv8. Here's an example using Swift v2.3 (v2.3 vs v3.0 is an unimportant distinction to framework feature detection):

```
convenience init(moc: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        self.init(context: moc)
    }
    else {
        let name = NSStringFromClass(self.dynamicType)
        let entityName = name.componentsSeparatedByString(".").last!
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(entityName, inManagedObjectContext: moc)!
        self.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc)
    }
}
```

The real question you have to ask yourself is why are you embracing Core Data features ahead of your customers?